# Ember.Select valueBinding with multiple set to true doesn't work

Tags: ember.js

I got this demo from the [Ember documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html). It is a select-box with a value assigned.

```
App.programmers = [
  Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Yehuda", id: 1}),
  Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Tom",    id: 2})
];

App.currentProgrammer = Ember.Object.create({
  id: 2
});
```

View:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="App.programmers"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
   valueBinding="App.currentProgrammer.id"}}
```

This case works and the "Tom"-item is selected.

When I add the attribute: `multiple="true"` to the Ember.Select, the "Tom"-item is still selected. But I want that multiple items already are selected, so I changed `App.currentProgrammer` to this:

```
App.currentProgrammer = [
  Ember.Object.create({id: 1}),
  Ember.Object.create({id: 2})
];
```

But now nothing is selected anymore. Should I change the `valueBinding`-attribute?

Comment: There is a pull-request on Github regarding this problem: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/996

Answer (score 4):

You may use selectionBinding instead: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zikolach/Zu2Jp/)

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{view Ember.Select
    multiple="true"
    contentBinding="App.content"
    optionValuePath="content.type"
    optionLabelPath="content.label"
    prompt="Select a value"        
    selectionBinding="App.types"        
}}
{{#each App.types}}
    {{type}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.content = [
    {label: "This is type 1", type: "type1"},
    {label: "This is type 2", type: "type2"}
];

App.types = [
    App.content[0], App.content[1]
];
```

I agree that valueBinding is still not working.

Comment: what's the difference between valuebinding and selectbinding?

Comment: selectionBinding binds the entire content where as valueBinding binds only the value part i.e. optionValue